# Shell Programming File Search and Append

Tags: shell, search

I am trying to write a shell program that will search my current directory (say, my folder containing C code), read all files for the keywords "printf" or "fprintf", and append the include statement to the file if it isn't already done.

I have tried to write the search portion already (for now, all it does is search files and print the list of matching files), but it is not working. Included below is my code. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Code]

EDIT: New code.

```
#!/bin/sh
#processes files ending in .c and appends statements if necessary

#search for files that meet criteria
for file in $( find . -type f )
do
    echo $file
    if grep -q printf "$file"
    then
        echo "File $file contains command"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute commands in a subshell you need `$( command )`. Notice the `$` before the parenthesis.

You don't need to store the list of files in a temporary variable, you can directly use

```
for file in $( find . ) ; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

And with

```
find . -type f | grep somestring
```

you are *not* searching the file **content** but the file **name** (in my example all the files which **name** contains "somestring")

To grep the content of the files:

```
for file in $( find . -type f ) ; do
  if  grep -q printf "$file" ; then
    echo "File $file contains printf"
  fi
done
```

Note that if you match `printf` it will also match `fprintf` (as it contains `printf`)

If you want to search just files ending with `.c` you can use the `-name` option

```
find . -name "*.c" -type f
```

Use the `-type f` option to list only files.

In any case check if your `grep` has the `-r` option to search recursively

```
grep -r --include "*.c" printf .
```

Comment: Yes you are not grepping the file but the file name see my edit

Comment: If the question solved your problem you can accept it with the "OK" symbol under the arrows to vote

Comment: With regards to the line `if grep -q printf;`, am I supposed to put this grep command with an eval command or something? Upon running the code, I get the error "unknown operator -q".

Comment: The -q option is to tell grep not to produce any output (it will just set the return value). Which OS are you using? You can achieve the same effect with `grep fprintf $file > /dev/null`

Comment: Sorry I forgot an argument to grep (the file :-). See my edit

Comment: Thank you for the info! Unfortunately, I still get the same unknown operator error, even if I use the /dev/null option you mentioned. My code is as follows: `if [ grep -q printf $file ] (line break) then...`

Comment: No you don't have to use the brackets. Remove `[` otherwise grep and -q are interpreted as arguments to `[` (i.e., test)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks! However, I now get "grep: illegal option -- q Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . ." which I assume means my version of Unix doesn't understand -q? I removed -q to see what happens, and got the result "grep: can't open find". (Sorry for all of the questions! I'm trying to get this right.)

Comment: Cannot open find does not really make sense with my example: are you still using the temporary variable? You should edit your question by adding the code you are using now (leave the old one otherwise it will be difficult to understand the comments). And copy and paste it as text not an image.

Comment: Sorry my error I forgot the $() to execute the find. See my edit

Comment: Thank you for the edit! However, things just are not cooperating... it is now giving me an "unexpected $" error in that line. (Thanks for your patience, I really appreciate it!)

Comment: Sorry again I was on a train and some troubles typing. It is supposed to be `$( )` and not as I wrote `($ )`. See my edit

Comment: Thanks again for the help! Unfortunately, I don't think that was the issue... as in my code above, I entered the $ correctly, but it still produces a "$ unexpected" error. I am at a loss for why this is, because it seems as if everything is correct!

Comment: I just tried your last edit (copy&paste) and works on my systems (Mac OS X and Fedora). What are you using?

Comment: I am accessing my school's server through PuTTY on Win7. I believe the server is running SunOS (that's what I got when I ran uname -a).

Comment: Ok then check if bash is installed (i.e., /bin/bash exists) and use `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning.

Comment: Unfortunately, for all schoolwork we must use /bin/sh... an odd rule, but still a rule. So I'm not sure where to go from here if I can't use bash. However, all of your help is certainly worth the best answer, even if you have no more ideas! Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, /bin/sh is surely OK I just don't know which shell it is (I don't have a SunOS system to check). Can you get your system version? Or better which shell is /bin/sh?

Comment: I believe the server uses SunOS 5.1x? I will double check, but it is a recent version. On our systems, /bin/sh is the Bourne shell (so say my notes...)

Comment: What happens if you type `echo $( echo a )` in a shell? Bourne shell supports both ` $() ` and the backticks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this sort of thing with `sed -i`, but I find that distasteful.  Instead, it seems reasonable to use `ed` (`sed` is `ed` for streams, so it makes sense to use `ed` when you're not working with a stream).

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in *.c; do
    grep -Fq '#include <stdio.h>' $i && continue
    grep -Fq printf $i && ed -s $i << EOF > /dev/null
1
i
#include <stdio.h>
.
w
EOF
done
```

Comment: In a comment to Matteo's answer, you mention that your grep does not support `-q`.  If that is the case, replace `grep -Fq printf $i` with `grep -F printf $i > /dev/null`